# How can I read from an API which is continuously changing? [JAVA]

Tags: java, api, streaming, live

How can I read from a RESTful API in which the content is continuously changing?

I have created a client which reads from the api, but just once. I have just used URLConnection to read the information from it. But since the content is continuously being updated, should I have to wrapped my code in a loop to keep reading non-stop?

Just to clarify that there is nothing coming from that api that tells me when it gets updated.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't have it in a constant loop, however I would determine when to get updates based on where you need to use the information. For example, if you only need to use the information when the user presses a certain button, then get an update once the user presses that button. That assures that for all of your uses of the data it will always be up to date.

Comment: Hi VortixDev,
I have to create a "consumer" that reads from that api and due to the changing nature of the api this consumer have to keep reading from it. There is no action that any user have to do or whatsoever, so that´s why I auto-suggested the "loop" or some auto-scheduled action to keep reading from that url every x seconds.

Comment: If the sole point of it is to read from the API then I suppose it would be best to update every x period of time, as you suggest. You most definitely wouldn't want it to be a constant loop, though, as you'd be constantly sending requests to the web server (who I don't think would appreciate it!). If there is a point where the data is needed from the consumer, then that's when I would get the info, and if you never need the data then I'd be confused as to why you need to get the data in the first place

Comment: I would definetily create a servlet in which I would use the @scheduled notation to keep reading every X time from the server.  It is a liveStream sports and that´s why the need of being reading constantly.

with every read the information will be populated in a database that I need to create.